# Enum literal also used as parameter name

Tags: ada

I created the following example code:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type My_Type is
     (A,
      B,
      C);

   procedure Foo (The_Type : My_Type) is
   begin
      null;
   end Foo;

   procedure Bar (B : String) is
   begin
      -- Error
      Foo (The_Type => B);

      -- Ok
      Foo (The_Type => My_Type'Succ (A));

      -- Ok
      Foo (The_Type => My_Type'Value ("B"));
   end Bar;
begin
   Bar ("Hello");
end Main;
```

The literal `B` defined in the enum type `My_Type` is also used as a parameter name in the procedure `Bar`. Unfortunately the compiler assumes that in the procedure call `Foo (The_Type => B);` the `B` is the name of the parameter and not the literal `B` in the defined enum type. I found two not optimal solutions to solve the problem. Are there any other solutions if I am not interested in renaming the literal or the parameter name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the parameter B in procedure Bar hides the enumeration identifier B declared in the enclosing scope for procedure Bar. You need only name the scope with the parameter:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type My_Type is
     (A,
      B,
      C);

   procedure Foo (The_Type : My_Type) is
   begin
      null;
   end Foo;

   procedure Bar (B : String) is
   begin
      Foo (The_Type => Main.B);
   end Bar;
begin
   Bar ("Hello");
end Main;
```

Comment: Thank you. So simple. I tried it the following way (with no success): `Foo (The_Type => My_Type.B);`